# How to decide if these two maps are proper?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

We define a mapping $f$ of a topological space $X$ into a topological space $Y$ to be proper if the subspace $f^{-1}(C)$ is compact in $X$ whenever $C$ is a compact subspace of $Y$.

Now how to determine if the self-maps $f$, $g$ of the reals defined as $f(x):= x^m$ and $g(x):= a - x^m$ for all real $x$, where $a$ is real and $m$ a positive integer, are proper or not?

Comment: Remember that you have Heine-Borel, so that you just need to compute: $[a,b]^{1/m}$

Answer (score 1):

First recall that **the image of a compact set under a continuous function between topological spaces is itself compact**. This is proved by taking the given open cover on the image, using continuity to get an open cover of the original set, using compactness to reduce this to a finite open cover, and then taking the corresponding finite cover of the image set.

Then notice how if $m$ is odd, then $f$ and $g$ have (continuous) inverses $f^{-1}(y) = ~ ^m \sqrt y$ and $g^{-1}(y) =~^{m} \sqrt {a -y}$ which must map compact sets to compact sets.

If $m$ is even the problem is slightly harder. If $C$ is compact then the inverse map to $f$ is only defined over the positive numbers. So $f^{-1}(C)= f^{-1}(C ~\cap~[0, \infty) )$ Since $C$ is compact in $ \mathbb{R}$ it is also closed. $[0, \infty)$ is also closed, so the intersection is a closed subset of a compact set, which requires it to be compact. The inverse function to $f$ is well defined over our new compact set and thus maps it to a compact set.

The even case for $g$ can be done by a similar method. The only difference is that restriction of domain we must make to define the inverse map is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Daron, this is a good answer, but the usual way that $f^{-1}$ is defined is as a set-valued function such that $f^{-1}(B)=\{a: f(a)=b, b\in B\}$. Your method still works, but you have to do a bit of casework and be careful about the inverse image and the "inverse functions".